# set a form size more than 2128:1860

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, size

I need to let a form get bigger than 2128:1860 which seems to be the biggest dimension.
how can I expand it?

I've already tried expanding it via properties 
I'm working with Visual Studio, in C#

Comment: Are you getting any error messages?

Answer (score 4):

The maximum value for a form size is based on the resolution of the screen:

From the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/25w4thew%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The maximum value of this property is limited by the resolution of the
>   screen on which the form runs. The value cannot be greater than 12
>   pixels over each screen dimension (horizontal + 12 and vertical + 12).